# Finding a function for generating seeds

Tags: c++

I encountered such a challenge in the competition (see problem explanation below). I tried using a hash algorithm, using a combination of string features and a random number as input, but after searching for integer type (2 to the 31st power), I couldn't find the answer. How to design a function that adapts to the distribution probability based on this question?

```
static constexpr uint64_t LCG(uint64_t state) {
    return (state * 6364136223846793005ULL + 1442695040888963407ULL);
}

uint64_t hashInteger(int input) {
    uint64_t stateLow = input ^ 0x9e3779b97f4a7c15ULL; // XOR with a magic constant
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        stateLow = LCG(stateLow);
    }
    return stateLow;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

The following is an explanation of the problem.

**Given**

1. A **string** array, such as {820, 255, 022, 999, 131...}, with m elements, each consisting of **3 digits**.
2. **Collision range**, for example 1 3.
   Explanation:

a. Split the corresponding string to obtain 3 numbers. For example: 820, the segmentation yields 8, 2, and 0.

b. Corresponding to 3 numbers, you need to generate 3 sets of numbers, each consisting of 3 **non repeating** numbers.
For example: **123-128-289**

c. Calculate the number of collisions based on the generated 3 sets of numbers.
For example:
-If there is no 8 in 123, there will be no collision.
-If there is 2 in 128, collision occurs.
-If there is no 0 in 289, there will be no collision.

Among the three sets of numbers, if the total number of collisions is 1 and it falls within the collision range of 1-3, it is called a hit.

For each string, it is necessary to randomly generate three sets of numbers according to its own defined pattern.

Explanation: **The self defined pattern** conforms to a certain distribution probability and cannot fabricate data.

-If there are 100 strings in the string array, it is necessary to generate three sets of numbers 100 times, and all corresponding strings must meet the collision range.

Finally, count the total number of hits, and the number of hits must meet the following conditions.

3. **Number of conditions**, for example 3
4. Conditions.
   For example:

```
    1 10 3
    11 20 3
    21 30 3
```

Condition 1: The first string to the 10th string requires 3 hits
Condition 2: The 11th to 20th strings need to be hit 3 times
Condition 3: The 21st to 30th strings need to be hit 3 times

**Requirements**
**The self defined pattern** requires input of **random number(seed)** as a parameter, as well as **string characteristics** (this requires your observation and construction). And then output three sets of numbers through custom operations.

You need to find n such seeds (n<10) within a limited time (30s) and tell the regular construction.

Comment: *"I tried using a hash algorithm"* It seems you over-complicated things. Start from the condition to generate the numbers: one collision -> so number should have a specific digit, randomize the others...

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, initially my idea was the same as yours, which can ensure the speed of generation, but it does not meet the requirements of distribution probability - “conforms to a certain distribution probability“. Thank you for your modification!